# Post request with json string as body and add validation to it

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to add string input to spring boot application. The content type is json and I am trying to add validation to it.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/entries")
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@RequestBody @NotBlank(message = "{field.required}") String username) throws Exception {
        //some logic
    }

}
```

For some reasons, `@Notblank`  annotation does not work.

Is it right way to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203740/spring-web-mvc-validate-individual-request-params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to go would be creating a model/dto class and defining your `@NotBlank` on a String in this class. then just change your controller-code like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@RequestBody @Valid MyClass myClass) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
```

For more insights, look [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use those validations on method parameters.
You need to bind your parameter onto an object if you want validation. Then, you just have to add @Valid annotation.
See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345800/valid-in-spring-rest/35349407#35349407).